# File Location of Doc Shortcuts in Mac OS

Tags: macos, dock

Where are the files that represent the shortcuts on the dock located on the hard drive of a Mac OS computer?

Answer (score 2):

They aren't files; they're entries in ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dock.plist. This is a property-list file that stores all of the settings for the Dock, including the list of "persistent-apps" (the apps on the left side of the Dock) and "persistent-others" (the documents and folders on the right). You can view the preferences (translated from binary to a JSON-like format) with the command `defaults read com.apple.dock`, or navigate to the folder in the Finder, select the file, and press Command-Y to get a preview (translated to XML).

Comment: Sweet, this looks like a good answer though I won't be able to try it until Monday. Thank you, I'll accept it Monday if it works or otherwise comment.